# Does Sun gets Neecha Bhanga Raja Yoga?

Tags: astrology

Does lagna lord Sun (Leo asc) gets Neecha Bhanga or Neecha Bhanga Raja yoga?. The horoscope has Sun and Venus in Libra(3rd House). Saturn in Capricon(7th house). Moon in Leo(1st House).

Comment: Where is your third house lord (Venus) located.

Comment: Based on above it does not seem you have neechbhanga rajyog. Where is your Mars located

Comment: My Mars is located in Cancer(12 th house). I have a doubt sir. In my chart Sun and Venus are in the same house with Venus ruling Libra and Sun debilitated in Libra. Does Venus give Neecha Bhanga Raj yog to Sun as the Debilitated planet is with ruling planet?

Comment: Hi. Please see answer

Comment: Third house is not considered good along with dusthana houses 6,8,12 so various auspicious yogas in such houses usually show little to nil effect and have different type of Vipreet Raja Yoga among each other.Third house is associated with siblings, 3rd and 8th house are also described as Maraka(killer) houses as per BPHS http://jyotishvidya.com/ch44.htm Powerful Raja Yogas like Gajkesari, Panchmahapurush, Neechbhanga etc., form in Kendra(1,4,7,10) or Trikona(1,5,9) houses while wealth planetary mutual exchange yogas form in (2,5,9,11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright this took a while. The answer is **Yes**, Sun does not have a Neecha bhanga raja yoga but it is not because of Venus is in its own house with sun.

So first let me paste the relevant screenshot from Manteswara's Phaladeepika, astrology treatise from 13th century

[image]

Let's take the first point from above screenshot

27. Sun is debilitated in Libra. Libra's lord is Venus. Sun is exalted in Aries. Aries' lord in Mars. Mars is in 12th House and Venus is in 3rd House. And Venus is in Kendra from Mars (in this case 4th house from Mars)

That is why I asked in comments where is Mars located

P.S. Mars is also neecha because it is debilitated in Cancer :-)

Comment: Got it Sir. In the above picture according to point number 1. Saturn is exalted in Libra where my Venus is Debilitated. I have Saturn in my 7th house Capricon. Does this also give Neecha Bhanga Raja Yog?. If so when will I get the benefit from saturn?. I have currently Sun Mahadasha and Saturn Antardasha going on. Also from your answer, Mars which is causing Neecha Bhanga Raja Yoga also debilitated in my case in Cancer. Can one debilitated planet give Neecha Bhanga to another Debilitated planet?

Comment: I don't see how Saturn can give neecha bhanga raja yoga. It would help if you can pinpoint which of the clauses from screenshot says so. On whether Mars , being debilitated itself , can provide neecha bhanga to sun I would say not really. Unless it is also getting simultaneous neecha bhanga from elsewhere . I can see that Mars does get neechabhanga from Saturn (as per 29). So what does it all mean when overlayed with dashas? I guess see when you have Pratyantar dasha of Mars within Saturn's antardasha. But then that period will be so small (around 22 days) that it won't mean much

Comment: @Ajay Ganesan - Please do consider to upvote and accept answer if satisfied

Comment: @AjayGanesan - Btw it need not be the case that Mars has to get neecha bhanga in order for it to give positive results. It could also have been Parivartan yoga for instance. But thats not the case

Comment: @Ajay Ganesan - I see that you are referring to Notes as compared to clauses 27 to 30. And yes, as per Notes 1 it does seem Saturn gives neecha bhanga. But the notes are translator's interpretation . Clauses 27 to 30 are direct translation from Phaladeepika

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your time. Many of the Indian astrology books tell  more than 15 rules for Neecha Bhanga Raj yog. But I think those all are author's interpretation as you told. But only the clauses 27 to 30 you mentioned are the actual ones. Am I correct sir?

Comment: @Ajay Ganesan - you have to check sources. It may be the case that debilitated planets can give raja yogas because of being located in houses 3,6 etc alongwith other condition. Many a times books n websites club it under neecha bhanga raja yoga because of the way they structure content.